# Resetting "this.id" within a nested if statement

Tags: javascript

I have this function to control a memory game.
The user is presented by a serious of images, after some seconds the images disappear and then the user has to click on the images in a pre-decided order.

For instance the user first need to click on the image that represents a football, then a tree etc. If the user fails at anytime the game is over.

The problem now is that I can't reach the second nested if-statement. This.id is stuck to the first image clicked, is there a way to reset this.id so that the user can click a second image? Or other solutions?

```
          function flagsAddEventlistener() {
                if (this.id == correctOrderArray[0]) {
                    points += 1;
                    userMessageElement.innerHTML = "Correct answer";
                    this.src = `flags/${correctOrderArray[0]}.png`;
                    if (this.id == correctOrderArray[1]) {
                        points += 1;
                        userMessageElement.innerHTML = "Correct answer";
                        this.src = `flags/${correctOrderArray[1]}.png`;
                    }
                } else {
                    userMessageElement.innerHTML = "Faulty answer";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what you want to achieve? In the callback of an event listener, `this` will always be the element that fired the event

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the logic; can correctOrderArray have duplicate values at index 0 and 1? That's how it's coded right now--which may be what you intended, but it's difficult to reason about.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was wondering the same thing!

Comment: This was a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: What I want to do is to check that the user clicks on the images in a pre-decided order. It's part of a quiz hence the nested if statement. So the user needs to for instance first click on the picture that represent's a "tree", then on the picture that represents a "football" etc.

Comment: The code is still written with a nested if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to know how many times a user clicked on the image, you need to add a state (a variable defined outside your listener).

Here is a simple example:

```
let counter = 0;

function flagsAddEventlistener() {
    if (this.id == correctOrderArray[counter]) {
        points++;
        userMessageElement.innerHTML = "Correct answer";
        this.src = `flags/${correctOrderArray[counter]}.png`;
    } else {
        userMessageElement.innerHTML = "Faulty answer";
    }
    counter++;
}
```